# Why is my JFrame Icon not changing from the default java icon?

Tags: java, jframe, icons

I have tried several solutions for changing the icon of my application, but none have worked! I do not get any error when i do the following but it still won't change!? Please, can someone tell me where I am going wrong because i don't see any error, and I am not receiving any error either!

I even made sure that the icon I want to use is a 20x20 pixel icon, because I read somewhere that is the maximum size for an icon.

```
frame.setIconImage(
            new ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/images/bfc_icon.png")).getImage());
```

Why is this not working? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT:

I am testing if the file exists, turns out it does but it still is not being set as the application icon...why is this??

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("src/images/bfc_icon.png");
    if (url == null)
        System.out.println( "Could not find image!" );
    else
        frame.setIconImage(new ImageIcon(url).getImage());
```

Comment: what OS are you using ?

Comment: Did not really dive deep there, but it seems, if the image cannot be loaded, it simply will return null there instead of throwing an error in the constructor. You could try checking if the resource exists first, for example by testing if `getResourceAsStream(...) != null`

Comment: @FlorianSchaetz yes before it used to give me that it was null, however now with this line of code i am using it isnt giving an error but it isnt actually changing the icon either.

Comment: @SchiduLuca Mac

Answer (score 0):

```
private void formWindowOpened(java.awt.event.WindowEvent evt) {                                  
        try {
            // TODO add your handling code here:
            Image img=ImageIO.read(getClass().getResource("ur path"));
            this.setIconImage(img);
        } catch (IOException ex) {

        }
```

> this will work

Comment: do i need to call this method somewhere? Also if i do call it what do i use as the parameter? or can i just take the code from this method and put it after the frame is created?

Comment: this  jfram event and work when fram is start run and this method writ in jfram class in this form and in it(method) you can write any code you need

Comment: i tried but it didn't work, thank you for your help anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It seems a bit too late, but I hope this helps.
This problem probably happens when you called the `setIconImage()` before you initialize the JFrame.

---

I also had this problem with the code below (w/ Eclipse IDE):

```
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Apps.class.getResource("/ico.png")));
initComponents();
```

I accidentally solved the problem by swapping these two so it looks like this:

```
initComponents();
setIconImage(Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getImage(Apps.class.getResource("/ico.png")));
```

You should try to do it as well, at least call the `setIconImage()` after the JFrame has initialized if you didn't use any window builder tool.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I just simply copied the picture I want to use as my icon to the project folder and not the src folder (source code folder) and it worked.